# How to open a folder from a list in an Excel spreadsheet using VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

```
Dim strFolderPath As String 
strFolderPath = “C:\temp\” 
ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink (strFolderPath)
```

This code opens a specific folder, but I need to open a folder saved in an Excel sheet as shown below:

[image: 1 Mohammed]

I need the code to read the path and to open the folder using the existing path in Excel

Comment: Are you trying to open all of the paths listed or only a specific one? What criteria are you picking the folder path with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean something like below?

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")   
    Range("C2").Hyperlinks(1).Follow
End with
```

If your addresses aren't actually hyperlinks:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")   
    ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:=.Range("C2").Value, NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True
End with
```

Also, note your values currently don't have any extention. You might want to add these in cell or through VBA:

```
Address:=.Range("C2").Value & ".extention"
```